# Use Sentry with Flutter in release build

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sentry

I'm trying to add Sentry integration into my Android project. I'm using dart sentry plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/sentry). When I build debug version then everything works correctly and I see in Sentry dashboard logged errors/crashes. Unfortunately when I try run exactly the same code in release mode then I don't see any Sentry activity.
I've tried to use apk build as:

```
flutter build apk
```

or run the application in release mode:

```
flutter run --release
```

In both cases, I don't receive anything in Sentry.io and even I don't see any activity in console (crash occurs). Problem is that when I try to debug code then everything starts working correctly (I see Sentry logs).

Any hints or advice?

**Edit**

I'm using Sentry logging gist helper:
https://gist.github.com/escamoteur/57d37e712befd8bd377f15c85136dcec

In debug and release mode I have disabled proguard. Based on the above gist I've noticed that.

*Debug*

Everything works correctly. I see in the console that exception is cached at line 110 (gist file) and after that, I see created Sentry event id.

*Release*

Execute exactly the same case as above (pass null into Navigator) doesn't trigger any action. I don't see anything in the console and when I put print("TEST") at line 110 (gist file) I still don't see anything.

Comment: You have no events? You likely will have mangled stack traces if you don't upload your proguard/R8 mapping files. Also the flutter SDK would need to add the file "id" in the event, so Sentry knows which mapping file to lookup

Comment: @BrunoGarcia I've put extra info in main post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your app's

> android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml